# I want to make a trace hanoi stack Using Stack

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, trace

I need to make Tracing in Java Using Stack with game Tower of Hanoi.

**Note:** I need 4 Times and show the Role of Stack please

This is my code in java :

```
package towersofhanoi;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TowersofHanoi {

    public void TOH(int n, String start, String aux, String end) {

           if (n == 1) {
               System.out.println(start + " -> " + end);
           } else {
               TOH(n - 1, start, end, aux);
               System.out.println(start + " -> " + end);
               TOH(n - 1, aux, start, end);
           }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

           TowersofHanoi towersOfHanoi = new TowersofHanoi();

           System.out.print("Enter number of discs: ");
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           int discs = scanner.nextInt();
           towersOfHanoi.TOH(discs, "A", "B", "C");
    }

}
```

This is my Stack (Empty) :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmSwk.jpg)

Comment: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/TowersOfHanoi.java.html

Comment: thanks but i need to show the reflication in stack !

Comment: What? No really, what?  What do you mean "show the reflication in stack"? What is "stack"? You linked an image of a rectangle that tells us *nothing.*

Answer (score 0):

In my country Tower of Ha Noi can be solve same : [image]

And when I edit your code stack not empty
[image]
Maybe you missing `int discs = scanner.nextInt();`